# General rules for training the RNN model when loss stops decreasing

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, torch, recurrent-neural-network

I have an RNN model. After about 10K iterations, the loss stops decreasing, but the loss is not very small yet. Does it always mean the optimization is trapped in a local minimum?

In general, what would be the actions should I take to address this issue? Add more training data? Change a different optimization scheme (SGD now)? Or Other options?

Many thanks!

JC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are training you neural network using a gradient vector based algorithm such as `Back Propagation` or `Resilient Propagation` it can stop improving when it finds a local minimum and it is normal because of the nature of this type fo algorithm. In this case, the propagation algorithms is used to search what a (gradient) vector is pointing.

As a suggestion you could add a different strategy during the training to explore the space of search instead only searching. For sample, a `Genetic Algorithm` or the `Simulated Annealing` algorithm. These approaches will provide a exploration of possibilities and it can find a global minimum. You could implement 10 itegrations for each 200 iterations of the propagation algorithm, creating a hybrid strategy. For sample (it's just a pseudo-code):

```
int epochs = 0;
do
{
   train();

   if (epochs % 200 == 0)
      traingExplorativeApproach();

   epochs++;
} while (epochs < 10000);
```

I've developed a strategy like this using `Multi-Layer Perceptrons` and `Elman recurrent neural network` in `classification` and `regressions` problems and both cases a hybrid strategy has provided better results then a single propagation training.